# onBackPressed not called when search view is open

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I click on the search view and enter data to search, the result is shown and I click the search result to go to Detail Fragment and now if I press back button it doesn't work. I have to press back button twice to go back to ListFragment. However it works fine when I press up button.
What could be the reason for this ?

**Edit 1 :** (Adding code snippet)

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            menu.clear();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.defect_search, menu);
            mIsMenuInflated = true;
            mSearchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
            mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(mSearchItem);
            mSearchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search_defect_hint));
            mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
            mSearchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(this);

            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }


public void onClickDefect(Integer defectId) {
        hideKeyboard(mActivity);
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.frame_content, DefectTabFragment.newInstance(defectId))
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
```

And In onBackPressed() of Activity I pop the fragment.

Comment: you need to share some code from your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If your `SearchView` is in `open` state then you should press `back` button `twice` to go back to `ListFragment`.

From [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html):

> By default, the `searchable activity` receives the `ACTION_SEARCH` intent
>   with a call to `onCreate()` and a new instance of the `activity` is
>   brought to the top of the `activity stack`. There are now two instances
>   of your `searchable activity` in the `activity stack` (so pressing the
>   `Back button` goes back to the previous `instance` of the `searchable`
>   `activity`, rather than exiting the `searchable activity`).

Hope this will help~

Comment: Yes that's absolutely fine in ListFragment and that's how the working should be. But the same behavior is seen in DetailFragment as well, don't know why ?